# How to turn a folder into jar file

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line

Is there any idea how can I turn a folder into jar file using batch file
I looked on the internet and I found somthing like:

```
jar cvf program.jar -C path/of/class/files
```

But I won't to list all class files
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean `But I won't to list all class files`

Comment: Maybe *won't* should really be *don't want*, though they are of course not equivalent :)

Comment: Jars are zip files with additional metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html.

It explains how to use the `jar` tool. `-C dir` simply changes the current working directory to `dir` and should be followed by `inputfiles` -- so maybe `-C path/of/class/files .` fixes your situation? Another option you could try would be to remove `-C` altogether and just state `path/of/class/files` as `inputfiles`, that should actually recursively traverse this directory and add everything.